# Asp.Net Identity - SetPasswordHashAsync not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2, ef-database-first

I am stuck into a scenario which goes something like this.

I am implementing **Identity 2.0** with my new **MVC** application. I want to go with the **database first** approach with **User Id** as **int**.

To accomplish this, I created

- Custom User Store - MyUserStore

  ```
   public class MyUserStore : IUserLoginStore<AspNetUser>, IUserClaimStore<AspNetUser>, IUserRoleStore<AspNetUser>, IUserPasswordStore<AspNetUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<AspNetUser>, IUserStore<AspNetUser>, IDisposable //where AspNetUser : AspNetUser
      {
          private readonly DemoPermissionDBContext _context;
          //private readonly Func<string, string> _partitionKeyFromId;

          public MyUserStore(DemoPermissionDBContext dbContext)
          {
              _context = dbContext;
          }

          public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(AspNetUser user, string passwordHash)
          {
              user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
              return Task.FromResult(0);
          }

          //And other methods implementation
       }
  ```

Here **AspNetUser** is the user class which is generated by EF and i made it inherited from Identity.IUser

- Custom User Manager - AppUserManager

  ```
       public class AppUserManager : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<AspNetUser>
       {
            MyUserStore _store = null;

            public AppUserManager(MyUserStore store) : base(store)
            {
                 _store = store;
            }

       }
  ```
- Custom Password Hasher - MyPasswordHasher

  ```
  public class MyPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
  {
      public string HashPassword(string password)
      {
          return password;
      }

      public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(
        string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
      {
          if (hashedPassword == HashPassword(providedPassword))
              return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
          else
              return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
      }
   }
  ```
- Custom Claim Prinicipal - AppClaimsPrincipal

  ```
   public class AppClaimsPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
   {
        public AppClaimsPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal principal):base(principal)
        { 

        }

        public int UserId
        {
            get { return int.Parse(this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value);
        }
   }
  ```

  Now, when i register user, **UserManager.CreateAsync** should automatically call the **SetPasswordHashAsync** before actually saving the user to DB. At the same time, **SetSecurityStampAsync** is being called properly.

What i do in my AccountController is something like this,

```
public AppUserManager UserManager { get; private set; }

public AccountController(AppUserManager userManager)
{
    this.UserManager = userManager;
    this.UserManager.PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher();

}
```

This is how i have implemented identity to user int primary key for users table and database first approach.

**Question:**

When my user is inserted in database, it has no password hash included. The record has null password hash. When i debugged the code, i found that **SetPasswordHashAsync** is not called only. It does not execute the menthod. What should be causing this issue? I have checked the entire code line by line but no success. Is there anything that i need to add that in web.config for using custom password hasher?

I am not sure if i am missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and found this question.. not sure if it's same as your problem, but eventually (and obviously in the end..) I found that I was calling `UserManager.CreateAsync(user)` when I should have been calling `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password)`, otherwise the password doesn't get used and the hashing functions don't get called.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you setting `MyPasswordHasher` in userManager. Add

```
this.PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher();
```

in constructor of `AppUserManager`.

Also you don't need to override `ClaimsPrincipal` to get `UserId` out. This is available through `User.Identity.GetUserId()`, available in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace.

Also I find it easier to have extension methods on `IPrincipal` to get values of claims out - easier than messing about with custom principal type.

Answer (score 0):

As *steve16351* mentioned `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password)` should be called instead of `UserManager.CreateAsync(user)`.

I've recently faced the exact same problem as you and solved it with `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password)`.